# My k8s liveness probe isn't setting the Host

Tags: django, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a Django app with startup and liveness probes configured. As it's a Django app, I need the `Host` header on the probes to match something permitted in my `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. As my probes are both `httpGet` checks, the simplest solution seems like it would be to use the `httpHeaders` field as [suggested in the kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes).

This seems to work for the startupProbe, however it's not working for the livenessProbe.

Sanitized version of my probes:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    httpHeaders:
      - name: Host
        value: k8s-probes
    path: /health/liveness
    port: http
    scheme: HTTP
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    httpHeaders:
      - name: Host
        value: k8s-probes
    path: /health/
    port: http
    scheme: HTTP
```

When the pod startups up, I see 200 responses to the initial startup probes, then once the liveness probe starts, I get 400 responses with the error that the pod IP address isn't in ALLOWED_HOSTS, indicating k8s isn't setting the Host header I've defined for the liveness probe.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `k8s-probes`?

Comment: Actual value is the internal cluster hostname for the service, `pod-name.namespace`. It's identical between the 2 probes, I've checked that extremely carefully.

Comment: Can you show your Django application code where you've set this `liveness` endpoint?

Comment: I cannot and it wouldn't be relevant. Django is rejecting the request based on the host not being in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. It never reaches my health code in the case of the livenessProbe, and in the case of the startupProbe, the Host header is set as defined in the httpHeaders field and everything runs correctly.

Specifically on the livenessProbe rejection, Django logs that the host header is being set as the IP of the pod.

Comment: @Endophage : Are you using the same HTTP request before and after enabling probes? 
Can you provide the requests which you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Prior to moving this service into kubernetes the equivalent probes were being handled by external services that used publicly accessible domain names the ALLOWED_HOSTS were configured to accept.

I don't control the specifics of HTTP request kubernetes makes for the configured probes and it's obviously different because the default Host header will be the Pod IP in the case of the Kubernetes probe. I'm attempting to override that Host using the documented approach but it's only working on the startup probe, not the liveness probe

Comment: Make sure that your application returns a 200 OK on the basepath "/" and not e.g. a redirect, as this makes your health check fail. Make sure you allow HTTP GET requests without authentication on the basepath "/".Another more tricky reason is that your application startup time might exceed the initialDelay of liveness/readiness probe and thus the check fails too often before the application is even ready. In that case either add more CPU power or increase the delay in the liveness probe.

Comment: See this [issue(https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62594#issuecomment-397704299) for more information

Comment: @HemanthKumar I'm not sure you fully read and comprehended the issue. The service is receiving the request and returning 400 from Django middleware because the Host header isn't in Django's list of ALLOWED_HOSTS. So, the service is up, and it's not returning a redirect. It is handling the requests, but kubernetes, given the same `httpHeaders` config for the liveness and startup probes, only seems to be using the `httpHeaders` for the startupProbe and not for the livenessProbe.

Comment: @Endophage setting the Host header should normally work with liveliness probes as well. Your URL configured is `/health/liveness` and Django usually sends a redirect in case of missing slashes, this redirect when followed will end up getting a wrong host header. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660033/14991864

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up using this configuration (thanks to @endophage for the hint)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    os.environ['DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS'],
    os.environ['POD_IP'],
]
```

and in the deployment:

```
env:
  - name: POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, the simplest solution i found online was to add `gethostbyname(gethostname())` in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. This only requires adding `from socket import gethostname, gethostbyname` in the settings.py file

There might be some caveats regarding security, and this post [of the mozilla marketing engineering & Ops teams](https://mozilla.github.io/meao/2018/02/27/django-k8s-elb-health-checks/) attacks the problem, if you're looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. We ended up using the kubernetes feature that enables us to expose runtime pod config, in this case the IP address, as an environment variable in the pod. We read that specific env var and add it to the ALLOWED_HOSTS. That locks down the allowed hosts much more than using your example.

If you want to re-write your answer I'll happily accept it. Otherwise I'll try to get around to writing up how we did it in the next week.