# Kubernetes health check always fails for django application

Tags: python, django, docker, kubernetes

I'm kinda new to kubernetes and I'm trying to figure out how to configure my health check.
When I configure my `livenessProbe` it always returns a 400, but when I remove the probe, exec into the pod, and run `curl 127.0.0.1/health` I get `{"status": "ok"}`.

(I'm running this locally on a minikube host)

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
# setup env variables
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
ENV DockerHOME=/app/django-app
# Expose port
EXPOSE 8000
# create work dir
RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
# set work dir
WORKDIR $DockerHOME
# copy code to work dir
COPY . $DockerHOME
# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# move working dir to where manage.py is
WORKDIR $DockerHOME/flag_games
# set default command (I thinkk)
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
# run commands for app to run
CMD ["manage.py", "collectstatic", "--noinput"]
CMD ["manage.py", "runserver", "localhost:8000"]
```

Here's my `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flag-game-deployment
  labels:
    app: flag-game-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flag-game-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flag-game-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker-django
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: docker-django
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 8000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
```

Here's the steps to my makebuild

```
minikube-deploy:
    make docker-build
    minikube start
    minikube image load $(IMAGE_NAME)
    kubectl apply -f "$(PWD)\manifests\deployment.yaml"
    kubectl expose deployment $(KUBE_DEPLOYMENT_NAME) --type=NodePort --port=8000 --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

and here's my views.py and url.py for my healthcheck

```
def health_check(request):
    # Perform any checks to determine the health of your application
    is_healthy = True

    # Return a JSON response with the health status
    if is_healthy:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'}, status=503)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('world_flags/', include('world_flags.urls')),
    path('health', views.health_check),
]
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably the 400 error is caused by having no `Host` header, which Django requires to match a whitelist. Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes readiness check does not correctly set HTTP host header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539630/kubernetes-readiness-check-does-not-correctly-set-http-host-header)

Comment: Hey, so I tried adding 
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: .localhost
and 
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: 127.0.0.1
an neither worked, or am i miss-understanding something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue

My path for `livenessProbe` in `deployments.yaml` should have been `/health/` instead of `/health`